# surfaceCreated() called after reopening app

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm currently working on getting the onStop() and onResume() methods right. The problem that I have is that my surfaceCreated()  methode gets called everytime when I reopen the app through the onResume() methode. Because the game gets initialized in the surfaceCreated() method, which obviously causes the game to restart. But my goal is to make that it's just continues where it stopped.
I tried to stop the initializing process with the boolean started, but this causes the app to crash even it got initialized at the start.

```
    public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    public MainThread thread;
    private static MainActivity context;
    private boolean started = false;

    public GamePanel(MainActivity context){
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(this.getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if(!started){
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            thread.start();
            }
            thread.setRunning(true);
        }

    }

   @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I removed all the unimportant stuff

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private GamePanel gamePanel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
    setContentView(gamePanel);
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    gamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);
}
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    gamePanel.thread.setRunning(false);
}
}
```

Im stopping the thread by setting thread.running to false. Which should pause the app logic and only continues as soon the onResume() method is called by setting thread.running to true again.
Do i have to recreate the SurfaceView everytime i reopen the app?

Im new to android and i couldn't find the solution on the web.
Thanks in advance!